# Complex sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis, clauses, complex-sentences

> So we don't consider forms like
>
> - *Created from a fusion of the animal’s top lip and its nose, the elephant’s trunk is a multi-functional tool*.
>
> as a complex sentence depending on the concept that the participle
> part at the beginning is a phrase not a clause, for it doesn't contain
> a subject neither does the verb indicate a tense?

Source: Comments section under an article at [British Council: *Participal Clauses*](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/participle-clauses?page=1)

Your reply would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: The answer to this question will depend on which school of grammar you subscribe to. Please indicate who you are referring to by 'we' when you say 'We don't consider...'.

Comment: Well, what's your opinion about this sentence? 'Created from a fusion of the animal’s top lip and its nose, the elephant’s trunk is a multi-functional tool.' Do you consider it as a complex one or no? reasons? Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Any English sentence that contains two or more words that may function as predicates grammatically can be considered a complex sentence, because it is never clear whether a subordinate clause need contain a subject, as long as it contains a predicate (noun, verb, adjective).

Comment: A good working definition of a protoypical clause is one that has a subject-predicate structure, though the subject may be understood rather than overt as is the case with most non-finite clauses. Incidentally, avoid the British Council site. The grammar it teaches is riddled with errors or inaccuracies.

Answer (score 3):

*The Middle School Handbook* defines a complex sentence as:

> A complex sentence has one independent clause and at least one
> dependent clause. (p206)

Elsewhere it defines a clause as:

> A clause is a group of words that contains a verb and its subject and
> is used as part of a sentence. (p163)

On the basis of these two definitions, your sentence is not a complex sentence, since *Created from a fusion of the animal's top lip and its nose* is not a clause.

This analysis seems to be shared by the "*We*" referred to in the first word of your post.

Modern grammarians regard nonfinite structures such as *Created from a fusion of the animal's top lip and its nose* as clauses. So some might categorize your  sentence as complex.

But *The Cambridge Gramar of the English Language* in its footnote on page 45 rejects this simplistic categorization of sentences:

> ...no great significance attaches to this latter distinction (i.e.
> between simple and complex clauses) and we shall not make further use
> of these terms.

Comment: I take it that the bottom line is that 'Do you consider it [the example sentence] as a complex one or no?' is asking for a yes/no answer when the question itself is considered either open to debate, or meaningless, by modern grammarians? Do we have a breakdown of the numbers adhering to different schools of thought?!

Comment: @Edwin. I suspect that English language teaching (to English native speakers) in schools is still heavily based on popular textbooks such as _The Middle School Handbook_ or _Warriner's English Grammar and Composition_ and defines sentence types traditionally. I have no idea to what extent more modern approaches to sentence types are taught. I care little about the classification and terminology of various grammatical features of the language. But it is useful for  students to know exactly what the teacher means when she gives grammatical and writing advice, and uses the metalanguage.

Comment: Yes. It's not easy when students find their trusted teacher hadn't realised that some approaches once seen as sacrosanct have now been ditched by respected linguists.

Comment: I'm on record elsewhere to the effect that questions asking for parts of speech, sentence types, and tense names from grammar-school lists are off  limits because they're nonsense. As the late P.J. O'Rourke put it so well, opinions about grammar are as interesting as opinions about arithmetic.

Comment: @Shoe Stick with CGEL, the most authoratative grammar of English ever written, and you won't go far wrong.